# jQuery Facebox in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Sorry bad english.
I'm working with jQuery Facebox. I have a `<div>` refreshed by `.load()`, and every time the `.load()` works in a loop, I do a new search for the `a[rel*=facebox]`. That's my source code:

```
setInterval(function() {
    $("#upfileslist").load("upfileslist.php", function() {
         $('a[rel*=facebox]').facebox({
            loadingImage : 'images/loading.gif',
            closeImage   : 'images/closelabel.png'
          });
    }
    );
}, 5000);
```

Aren't only links from the "upfileslist" div that are used Facebok.

In Google Chrome, that's working fine, but in Mozilla Firefox, the Facebox start appearing, and then, the page is refreshed and the target is loaded in full window, instead of in the Facebox box. This error appears:

> Time: 25/09/2012 10:50:13
>
> Error: TypeError: $("a[rel*=facebox]").facebox is not a function
>
> File: http://my_js_file.js
>
> Line: 9 (closeImage   : 'images/closelabel.png')

Thanks.

Comment: Just checking you have included jQuery in your page?

Comment: I think the path of js file is not valid as result this function is not working...or you have declare above `facebox.js` file as if valid path so call `setinterval` below this js file

Comment: jQuery is included. This error only exists when using Mozilla Firefox. In anothers browsers, everything works fine.
And the facebox.js is included before the file where are the error.